# How to change MediaWiki "Main Page" title?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I just installed Media Wiki on [my web site](http://keeganmccarthy.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) for a club at my school.  I can't figure out how to change the "Main Page" title though on the home page.  Does any one know how I can do this?

Comment: The marked duplicate question is subtly different in that they've mentioned trying to do something with DISPLAYTITLE. That's another solution I hadn't thought of, but it's for changing the displayed title without changing the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you do it : [Changing the Title of the Media Wiki Page](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/mediawiki/mediawiki_page.htm)

- It looks identical to the wiki you have installed on your website.
- And it's very simple, Login as `Administrator` and use the `[Move]` link on top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix is to just 'move' the Main Page to a different page name. [Help:Moving a page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Moving_a_page). Because this leaves behind a redirect, visitors will be taken to the new page title. Do this as the first step.

However this is half solution because you'll always see the little "redirected from 'Main Page" text at the top, the URL still contains 'Main_Page', and the side bar on the left does too.

For a more complete and correct way to tell MediaWiki a new home page title, you should alter the contents of 'MediaWiki:Mainpage' to point to a different title. This is a special 'system message' pages which you cannot modify without having administrator rights. Set yourself up with administrator rights if you didn't do this already.

After a refresh this should also change the 'Main Page' link in the sidebar, but if it does not, you may need to modify the 'MediaWiki:Sidebar' system page.

This is on the [MediaWiki FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_change_which_page_is_the_main_page.3F)

One other approach is to use a [DISPLAYTITLE magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#DISPLAYTITLE), but this has several disadvantages: This is only used for modifying the display of the title of the page, but the URL will (confusingly!) still be "Main_Page". It's only really intended for subtle modifications of the page title display (e.g. capitalisation changes), and won't allow you to do more unless you make a config change: [$wgRestrictDisplayTitle=false](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRestrictDisplayTitle), which applies throughout your wiki. Finally the magic word will be visible in your wiki text, which may or may not bother you. All in all, not a great solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "MediaWiki:Pagetitle" and "MediaWiki:Pagetitle-view-mainpage"? Administrators can modify these - they change the title element of wiki pages. Or are you looking for "MediaWiki:Mainpage", which changes the page used as the main page?